# 'Technical Debt and Issues' widget. How is issue trend calculated

Tags: sonarqube

The '**Technical Debt and Issues**' widget in a **Sonarqube** dashboard includes an issue list broken down by severity *e.g.  Blocker,  Critical,  Major etc .*

The widget display displays a trend arrow *(Up,  down,  no-change)* against each issue category.

A great feature,  but I'd wanted to know how this is calculated for the default view.

If you select a time-change category of '*Since Previous Analysis*'  or '*over 30 days*',  the answer is self-evident, its the delta in the selected periods.  However not sure about the default where no period is selected.

Reason for the question is that I have a current project where a couple of categories have downward trends over '*previous*' and '*over 30 days*',  but this isn't reflecting as a downward trend in the default view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computation of the trend is different from the differential periods. It uses the last analyses to guess the evolution of the measure for the given metric. This is why you can have some differences between what you see in the differential periods (depending on what you configured) and the trend icon.

If you really want to know how this trend is computed, you can take a loot at the [TendencyAnalyser.java](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/plugins/sonar-core-plugin/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/core/timemachine/TendencyAnalyser.java) class in SonarQube source code.